# Use the button defined behind in C# in front bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, c#, html, bootstrap-modal

I write this to have a floating window shows up after I click open modal button

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="imghere">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in this example, I defined the button with

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Now I have a button defined in C# loop in behind

```js
protected void GenGridView()
    {
        var data = project.ObtainDataDescJSON();
        Title = "show";
        for (int rowCtr = 0; row < data.Num.Count; row++)
        {
            var buttonField = new ButtonField
            {
                ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
                Text = "Show",
                CommandName = "Display"

            };
            ModelNumFieldsGrid.Columns.Add(buttonField);
            break;
        }
      }
```

How can I use these buttons I defined in C# in the bootstrap modal? How should I change the

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

should I use something like get element By ID? I really new to Web developing, please help! Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time following along with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me edit it

Comment: So the C# code is how I define the buttons in behind. I want to use bootstrap modal in front. By click that button I defined in C# I want a floating dialog window shows up.

Comment: I only know how to accomplish floating window with button defined in front with html. I dont know how to do that with buttons defined in behind in C# loop

Comment: @jgabb I add some comments, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular button, not a button field but either way this should do it. Or you can just use jQuery to find all of the buttons you added and attach the attributes that way (preferred).

```
protected void GenGridView()
    {
        var data = project.ObtainDataDescJSON();
        Title = "show";
        for (int rowCtr = 0; row < data.Num.Count; row++)
        {
            var buttonField = new ButtonField
            {
                ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
                Text = "Show",
                CommandName = "Display"

            };

            buttonField.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
            buttonField.Attributes.Add("data-target", "#myModal");
            buttonField.CssClass = "btn btn-info";             

            ModelNumFieldsGrid.Columns.Add(buttonField);
            break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Error 3 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\s0043306\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\PredictiveModeling\ModelFields.aspx.cs 54 25 PredictiveModeling

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have error about no extension method Attributes and no extension method cssClass

Comment: I tried to add using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute; but error said Error 2 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is a type not a namespace C:\Users\s0043306\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\PredictiveModeling\ModelFields.aspx.cs 11 7 PredictiveModeling

Comment: Just use a regular button and not a button field.

Answer (score 0):

```js
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "modelBox", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
```