# No extension method attribute How can I solve it

Tags: c#, extension-methods

When I use

```js
protected void GenGridView()
    {
        var data = project.ObtainDataDescJSON();
        Title = "show";
        for (int rowCtr = 0; row < data.Num.Count; row++)
        {
            var buttonField = new ButtonField
            {
                ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
                Text = "Show",
                CommandName = "Display"

            };

            buttonField.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
            buttonField.Attributes.Add("data-target", "#myModal");
            buttonField.CssClass = "btn btn-info";             

            ModelNumFieldsGrid.Columns.Add(buttonField);
            break;
        }
      }
```

to define buttons in C# I got error said no extension attributes and no extension cssClass.

I tried

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
```

and

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute;
```

but doesn't work. How can I solve it

My exact errors

```js
Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\s0\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Model.aspx.cs 55 25 Pred

Error 7 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' does not contain a definition for 'CssClass' and no extension method 'CssClass' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\s06\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Model.aspx.cs 74 25 Pred
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `buttonField`?

Comment: Cool! let me update my posts

Comment: The actual error message would help too - I'm sure it's not "no extension attributes and no extension cssClass"

Comment: I have edited my posts do you mean this part?

Comment: what versions of .net are you using? this moved between 4.0 and 4.5

Comment: MSDN says there is no property `Attributes` nor `CssClass` on `ButtonField`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods in C# allow you to declare methods that you can call *as if* they were methods of a class:

```
public class Button { } 

public static class ButtonExtensions 
{
    public static int GetArea(this Button button)
    {
        return button.Width * button.Height;
    }
}
```

With this extension method, you can call:

```
Button b = new Button();
int area = b.GetArea();
```

When you remove the extension method, you get the error message

> 'Button' does not contain a definition for `GetArea` and no extension method `GetArea` accepting a first argument of type `Button` could be found

Now there probably never was an extension method `Attributes` or `CssClass` but the compiler is *guessing* that it was there once, probably since most programmers won't even try compile when IntelliSense isn't picking up on the member names.

In short: the compiler is telling you that `ButtonField` does not have these members.

Comment: So, the only way to use extension method attributes is writing the Attribute method by myself? Actually this question is based on another question of mine. Can you take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217284/use-the-button-defined-behind-in-c-sharp-in-front-bootstrap-modal

Comment: The error is quite simple - you're trying to access properties that don't exist. But now you're throwing the terms "extension" and "attribute" around like you're trying to do something very complicated. To be honest I don't have a clue what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm totally new to Web Develope.I want to use the buttons defined in C# in the bootsrtap modal in front. By clicking a button I want to have a pop up window.But this button is defined in behind in C#. And I dont know how to use that button in front.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not contain a property called CssClass, you can set up the class through:

```
buttonField.ControlStyle.CssClass
```

Also if you need to add custom attributes to the ButtonField you need to do that in the event RowDataBound of your grid.